# Joining tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, error-000622, error-000728

What I am trying to accomplish is displaying the location of parcel numbers from an Excel table on a map. I have a shapefile with all the city parcels already mapped out so I was going to try and join the two tables but the join keeps failing. Each table has a field with parcel numbers so I thought this would be the route that I would take but am unsure.

[image: Image of the already mapped out parcels that I am trying to join the (Application intake) parcel numbers to][image: error I keep getting]

[image: error I receive]
[image: Image of the table that has the parcels I want displayed]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question so that the error message is included in the text of the question body.

Comment: Why not label your shapefile using the parcelno field?  As for the join if you save your spreadsheet to a dbf will most of the records join?  Fields over 10 characters aren't allowed in shapefiles.  Where you have multiple parcel numbers these will not join; you will need to create a separate record for each parcel number.

Comment: Could you screen shot what you entered into the tool?